# Dean has $20$ days and $4500$ acres in which to plant corn and soybeans

Tags: word-problem, operations-research

I was solving this problem:

> Dean has $20$ days in which to plant corn and soybeans. The corn can be planted at a rate of $250$ acres per day and the soybeans at a rate of $200$ acres per day. He has $4500$ acres available for planting these two crops. If the profit is $\$26$ per acre on corn and $\$30$ per acre on soybeans, how much of each should Dean plant? What is the maximum profit?

And I couldn't figure it out, so I just googled it and these inequalities came out;

X = acres of soy 
Y = acres of corn 
Then, the constraints are: 
Y/250 + X/200 <=20

X+Y <= 4500

X>=0, Y >=0

I get all of them, but what does Y/250 + X/200 <=20  represent? I thought the inequality has to be something like

250y+200x <= 4500

x+y<=20

Why am I wrong, and why is this Y/250 + X/200 <=20 correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not wrong. Both formulations are correct, but the meaning of $x$ and $y$ is different between the two.

In the Google solution $X$ and $Y$ represent acres, so, for example, $X/200$ has units of acres / (acres/day) = days, and the constraint $Y/250 + X/200 \le20$ is the constraint that Dean has 20 days to plant.

In your solution $x$ and $y$ represent days, so $x+y\le 20$ is the constraint that Dean has 20 days to plant.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't get Y/250+x/200 part. What does it represent? He can plant 250 and 200 acres a day, right? Then is it not y250+x200<= 20 or something close to it? Why do you have to divide?

Comment: I think division has something to do with the units as you presented it above, but I do not quite understand it.

Comment: $X/200$ is the number of *days* spent planting soybeans, and $Y/250$ is the number of *days* spent planting corn. So the sum of these is total days spent planting, which must be at most 20. You divide, since $X$ has units of acres, and $200$ has units of acres per day.  Another way to see this: (acres) = (acres/day) * (days). Now solve for (days).

Comment: Oh, so dividing the final product by its corresponding limitation in one day, we can discover how many days he has planted it. I get it now! Thank you! But one more concern; when I solved the equation with my inequalities, the solution was different, I mean the maximum. Is it supposed to be the same with both equations?

Comment: I don't know what your solution was, but remember that $X$ and $Y$ have different meanings in the two approaches. In the google approach the $X$ and $Y$ are acres, so the profit is $30X+26Y$. In your approach you have to convert the optimum $x$ and $y$ (which are days) into acres, then compute the profit from the acres.

Comment: .. so the profit would be $30(200x) + 26(250y)$

Comment: Amazing! Now I comprehend it fully. Thank you so much!